# Java: Secure storage for client password

Tags: java, security, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

Is there anything in Java that allows one to store client password in a secure location?

My app needs to work in offline mode. It should allow the user to create content, store it on the device and prevent other apps from reading this content. Other apps may access the content but they should not be able to decrypt it.

One classical solution will be to use a secure hash function to hash user password and use the result to encrypt the files. However, this involves user typing his/her password each time he/she accesses the app. I want to save the password in a secure way that will protect it from other apps on the device.

In Android, such solution is possible by using [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

Is there anything like that in pure Java?

Answer (score -1):

You can use java.security.MessageDigest with SHA as your algorithm choice. Example

```
public class CryptWithMD5 {
private static MessageDigest md;

  public static String 
cryptWithMD5(String pass){
try {
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] passBytes = pass.getBytes();
    md.reset();
    byte[] digested = md.digest(passBytes);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<digested.length;i++){
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & digested[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {

}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You cannot decrypt MD5, but you can compare outputs since if you put the same string in this method it will have the same crypted output.If you want to decrypt you need to use the SHA.You will never use decription for a users password.For that always use MD5

Comment: Note that both SHA and MD5 are insufficient and insecure for password storage. MD5 is insecure and broken in general (explaining this would not fit in a comment sorry, but don't use MD5 at all, and don't use SHA for password hashing).